# R SAX Parse attribute in empty element XML

Tags: r, xml, sax

I am new to R and I cannot find example of extracting specific attribute in an empty element, most example i found are extracting data value of a child nodes.

In a nutshell, how to extract an attribute using xmlEventParse() for XML like this:

```
<elements>
    <element attribute1="value" attribute2="value"/>
    <element attribute1="value" attribute2="value"/>
</elements>
```

Assuming I want to get **attribute1** on the **2nd element**.

Thanks in advance.

Update: Found the solution. It is xmlAttrs(root[[2]])[['attribute1']]